# Inserting iframe in jQuery with the if condition

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code for HTML and jQuery. I wanted to insert an iframe where it says : 'You clicked:' ... in a if statement, where if represents the condition of which state the user clicked on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.usmap.js"></script>
        <title>USA Map</title>

</head>
       <body>
               <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
               <div id="clicked-state"></div>

         <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#map').usmap({
                     // The click action
                     click: function(event, data) {
                         $('#clicked-state')
                         .text('You clicked: '+data.name)
                         .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);

                    }
                 });
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an iframe to your document, so you don't need to insert it with javascript.

```
<iframe id="stateFrame" src="default.html" name="stateFrame"></iframe>
```

Regarding which state was selected by the user, you're now able to load a specific page within this iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').usmap({

    // The click action
    click: function(event, data) {

        // Show some text
        $('#clicked-state').text('You clicked: ' + data.name);

        // Decide which page should be loaded
        if(data.name == "TX") // Texas was selected
        {
            $("#stateFrame").attr("src", "texas.html");
        }
        else if(data.name == "FL") // Florida was selected
        {
            $("#stateFrame").attr("src", "florida.html");
        }
        else // The selected state did not match our creteria, show default page
        {
            $("#stateFrame").attr("src", "default.html");
        }

   }
   });
});
```

Source: http://snipt.org/XJK7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .html instead of .text at this section `.text('You clicked: '+data.name)`

Comment: i tried .html instead of .text after you suggested and it works fine and the same way as .text works.